# Does CRC has the following feature

Tags: checksum, crc

When the data transmission is tampered 1 bit or 2 bits, can the receiver correct it automatically?

Comment: Which CRC algorithm?  How many bits?  This question is really quite vague.  Read the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) for more information.

Comment: Dude there is this awesome site,  i think its called like "wikipeida"  or something.  Idk man you should check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, CRC is an error-detecting code, not an error-correcting code.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Cyclic_redundancy_checks_.28CRCs.29)

Answer (score 0):

CRC is primarily used as an error-detecting code.  If the total number of bits (including those in the CRC) is smaller than the CRC's period, though, it is possible to correct single-bit errors by computing the syndrome (xor the calculated and received CRC's).  Each bit will, if flipped individually, generate a unique syndrome.  One can iterate the CRC algorithm to find the syndrome that would be associated with each bit; if one finds the syndrome associated with each bit, one can flip it and correct a single-bit error.

One major danger with doing this, though, is that the CRC will be much less useful for rejecting bogus data.  If one uses an 8-bit CRC on a packet with 15 bytes of data, only one in 256 random packets would pass validity, but half of all random packets could be "corrected" by flipping a single bit.

Comment: For this to work, CRC must be able to detect all 1 and 2 bit errors.

Comment: @philcolbourn: If a CRC has period N, the only two-bit errors it won't be able to detect for an arbitrary length input will be those where the errors are some multiple of N bits apart.  If the input stream is N bits or shorter, all two-bit errors will be detected.

Comment: Yes, that sound right. I think N is very large - larger than most packet or frame sizes for 16 and 32 bit CRC's. But for 8 bit CRCs it may be an issue - right?

Comment: A typical CRC of B bits will use a polynomial with one cycle of length 2^B-1 and one "cycle" of length 1.  I believe the fact that there's only one cycle of unit length won't cause double-bit-error problems in cases where the message length is accurately known, since since it could only hit that cycle in either the correct-bit or incorrect-bit case.  Still, it's sometimes advantageous to use a modified CRC which has two cycles of length 2^(B-1).

Comment: An 8-bit CRC is pretty good for guarding 14 bytes; a 16-bit CRC is good for guarding just under 8K.  An approach I would suggest when transmitting a large bunch of data is to use an 8-bit CRC on each packet, and a 32-bit CRC on each group of 16 packets or so.  If all of the packets in a group pass validation individually, but the group fails, reject the entire group.  The CRC overhead would be 1.25 bytes/packet (significantly less than a CRC-16) but the likelihood of an erroneous packet escaping detection would be much less.  There would be a moderate risk of an erroneous packet...

Comment: ...escaping "immediate" detection, but that would simply mean that 255/256 bad packets would require one packet to be retransmitted (the bad one), while one in 256 might require that 16 packets be retransmitted.  I'm not sure if that technique would be at all adaptable for forward-ECC applications, but it's a useful one to have in one's toolbox for data transmission.